# Erro no objeto JSON no php

Tags: php, angularjs

houve alguma modificação quando se cria ou se pega um objeto JSON no PHP?

tenho o seguinte código:

Angular:

```
$scope.atualizaUsuario = function(usuario) {
    $window.localStorage.setItem("nome", usuario.nome);
    $window.localStorage.setItem("usuario", usuario.usuario);
    $window.localStorage.setItem("email", usuario.email);

    var nome = $window.localStorage.getItem("nome", nome);
    var usuario = $window.localStorage.getItem("usuario", usuario);
    var email = $window.localStorage.getItem("email", email);
    var idUsuario = $window.localStorage.getItem("idUsuario", idUsuario);

    usuario = {
        "idUsuario":idUsuario,
        "nome":nome,
        "usuario":usuario,
        "email":email
    }

    $http.put("http://www.vigilantescomunitarios.com/php/atualizaUsuario.php", usuario).success(function (data){
        console.log(data);
        $location.path("/ajustes");
    })
}
```

Depois...

```
<?php
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);

$idUsuario = $request->idUsuario;
$name = $request->name;
$usuario = $request->usuario;
$email = $request->email;
$pass = $request->pass;
```

Faço essa pergunta, pois no logo do php aparece essa mensagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe o porque disso?
Valeu.

Comment: Já tentou dar um print_r($request) para ver o que imprime? Vi que vc está fazendo $request->name mas acredito que o certo seja $request->nome acho que assim já resolve o fatal error, mas da um print_r depois do decode para ver como está chegando o objeto. Depois do print coloca die;

Comment: Descobri o problema @AndréVicente.
Eu não tinha criado o objeto json, como coloque na atualização do post.
Valeu.